# Optimized solution for Comparison in 2D array

Tags: php

So i have this 2D array.

```
array (size=6)
  'US-20150018889-A1' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'US-13795596' (length=11)
      1 => string 'US-13713626' (length=11)
      2 => string 'US-11361942' (length=11)       // match 1
      3 => string 'WO-CH2003000577' (length=15)
      4 => string 'US-20150018889' (length=14)
  'US-20140018803-A1' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'US-11159064' (length=11)
      1 => string 'US-20140018803' (length=14)
  'US-8523858-B2' => 
    array (size=17)
      0 => string 'US-20060287652' (length=14)
      1 => string 'CN-101296665' (length=12)
      2 => string 'CA-2613278' (length=10)
      3 => string 'ZA-200711136' (length=12)
      4 => string 'KR-101334253' (length=12)
      5 => string 'JP-5138587' (length=10)
      6 => string 'TW-200709800' (length=12)
      7 => string 'EP-1893110' (length=10)
      8 => string 'IN-10213DELNP2007' (length=17)
      9 => string 'NZ-564765' (length=9)
      11 => string 'KR-1020080041619' (length=16)
      13 => string 'WO-2007001945' (length=13)
      14 => string 'TW-I392473' (length=10)
      15 => string 'AU-2006262507' (length=13)
      17 => string 'BR-PI0612275' (length=12)
      18 => string 'US-8523858' (length=10)
      19 => string 'JP-2008546479' (length=13)
  'US-8852245-B2' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'US-13713626' (length=11)
      1 => string 'US-11361942' (length=11)       // match 1
      2 => string 'WO-CH0300577' (length=12)      // match 2
      3 => string 'US-20130197589' (length=14)
      5 => string 'US-8852245' (length=10)
  'US-8845698-B2' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'US-11361942' (length=11)       // match 1
      1 => string 'WO-CH0300577' (length=12)      // match 2
      2 => string 'US-20130116735' (length=14)
      3 => string 'US-8845698' (length=10)
  'US-8343196-B2' => 
    array (size=29)
      0 => string 'WO-CH03000577' (length=13)
      1 => string 'CH-0300577' (length=10)
      2 => string 'EP-03818256' (length=11)
      3 => string 'WO-2005018472' (length=13)
      5 => string 'US-20060235400' (length=14)
      6 => string 'AU-2003254686' (length=13)
      8 => string 'DE-50312893' (length=11)
      9 => string 'EP-1731107' (length=10)
      11 => string 'BR-PI0318428' (length=12)
      12 => string 'EP-1741397' (length=10)
      14 => string 'IN-395DELNP2006' (length=15)
      15 => string 'CA-2536960' (length=10)
      16 => string 'JP-2007506450' (length=13)
      17 => string 'CN-1819799' (length=10)
      18 => string 'AR-045493' (length=9)
      19 => string 'TW-I329506' (length=10)
      20 => string 'DE-20321245' (length=11)
      21 => string 'DE-20321551' (length=11)
      22 => string 'DE-20321552' (length=11)
      26 => string 'EP-1658015' (length=10)
      27 => string 'IN-226296' (length=9)
      29 => string 'US-8343196' (length=10)
      30 => string 'JP-4999327' (length=10)
      33 => string 'CL-2004002168' (length=13)
      34 => string 'CL-21682004' (length=11)
      35 => string 'TW-200514540' (length=12)
      36 => string 'DE-20321151' (length=11)
      37 => string 'DE-20321244' (length=11)
      38 => string 'NZ-545392' (length=9)
```

I want to compare all the elements of each index with elements of all the other indexes. And if any of the elements from one index matches any of the elements from another index, I want to group those two indexes together, but i cannot lose the index values either.

i know **array_intersect** can do the comparing and grouping can be done after that, but it will require 2 loops, (n<sup>2</sup> complexity)

is there a better way to do it that can reduce the complexity of the logic?

i basically want to see which indexes are related to each other. (relation being common elements)

P/S:
Provide answers only if you have a more optimized way, because i've already implemented it via normal logic.
PHP's inbuilt functions would be helpful.

Comment: please suggest better array formation if it helps with optimization

Comment: What is the expected outcome for the provided example?

Comment: You can't do it better than that. You have to compare each list will all the other lists. That requires `n*(n-1)/2` comparisons of lists using `array_intersect`. `array_intersect()` itself also does `O(n^2)` comparisons between the elements from the two arrays it compares.